# How to store data consisting of articles and dates and other attributes for use in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am working with large textual data  (articles containing words, symbols,escape characters,line breaks etc). Each article also consists of attributes like date  , author etc.

It will be used in python for NLP purposes . What is the best way to store this data such that it can be read efficiently from disk.

### EDIT :

I have loaded the data as a pandas dataframe in python

Storing as a csv results in corruption due to line breaks(\n) in the text making the data unusable.

storing as JSON is not working due to encoding problems.

Comment: See [`pandas.to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)

Comment: storing as excel solves the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: pickle files are much faster to read than excel. I thought you were looking for the data to be "read efficiently from disk"